# calculate this integral $\int^{8}_{0} \pi y(y^{\frac{4}{3}}+1)dy$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to calculate the following integral, however, I'm stuck on how to proceed after this point:

$\int^{8}_{0} \pi y(y^{\frac{4}{3}}+1)dy$

1. $\pi\int^{8}_{0}  y(y^{\frac{4}{3}}+1)dy$

Multiply by conjugate
2. $\pi\int^{8}_{0}  y(y^{\frac{4}{3}}+1)dy$ = $\pi\int^{8}_{0} y(\frac{y^{\frac{8}{3}}-1}{y^{\frac{4}{3}}-1})dy$

Where to go from here

Comment: It is a power rule problem. Completely trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply power rule : \begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{8}{\pi y\left(y^{\frac{4}{3}}+1\right)\mathrm{d}y}&=\pi\int_{0}^{8}{y^{\frac{7}{3}}\,\mathrm{d}y}+\pi\int_{0}^{8}{y^{1}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &=\pi\left[\frac{y^{\color{red}{1+}\frac{7}{3}}}{\color{red}{1+}\frac{7}{3}}\right]_{0}^{8}+\pi\left[\frac{y^{\color{red}{1+}1}}{\color{red}{1+}1}\right]_{0}^{8}\\ &=\frac{3\pi}{10}\times 2^{10}+\frac{\pi}{2}\times 8^{2}\\ \int_{0}^{8}{\pi y\left(y^{\frac{4}{3}}+1\right)\mathrm{d}y}&=\frac{1696\pi}{5}\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**$$\int^{8}_{0} \pi y(y^{4/3}+1)\,dy$$
$$\int (y^{7/3}+y)\,dy=\frac{3 y^{10/3}}{10}+\frac{y^2}{2}+C$$